# MongoLab error - 'mongo not found'

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mlab

I am hosting an app on heroku and I'm trying to connect it to the MongoDB database using the MongoLab addon. One of the steps is to type:

`mongo ds044064-a0.mongolab.com:44064/heroku_w6fhwppg -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>`

But I keep getting the error "mongo not found" Anyone have any ideas why? The add-on is installed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mongo` refers to the mongo shell binary, which you'll need to install locally. It, along with all the other MongoDB binaries, can be downloaded here:

https://www.mongodb.org/downloads